# Private instance of pastebin like service

Tags: code-snippets, pastebin

I work behind a very strict firewall.  Any sharing of code is grounds for immediate dismissal (and aggressively enforced).

I would like to set up a pastebin-like environment for my global team.

I haven't been able to find any solutions that are able to support c#, sql, python, java, html  (primarily)

Does anyone know of any solution I might be able to install on a local server to use only internally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search the internet for "pastie like service" you can find some open source implementations.

For example, http://alternativeto.net/software/pastie/ lists quite a lot, one of them is at http://hastebin.com/ and does syntax highlighting

- [haste-server source code on github](https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-server)
- [haste-client source code on github](https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-client)

(If you need help to host such a service, let me know)